# automating a process

Tags: .net, automation

I have a long and annoying process which is using three different applications and I must do this every week I'm looking for a tool to automate all these steps .
all my applications are winform applications , basicly I need to open applications simulate button clicks or left clicks .

I have done the same thing for webforms using WATIN and now I'm looking for right tool doing the same for winforms .
thanks

Comment: Looks like a SuperUser.com candidate to me.

Comment: No mate I'm trying to develop an application using c# to do this .but anyway I don't mind anything that can do it is OK ,I just need to find the tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like AutoIt? http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Just launch the app using `System.Diagnostics.Process`, then use `FindWindow` to find the application, `SetForeGroundWindow` to make it the active app then use `SendKeys` to send keypresses and `SendInput` for mouse clicks.

If you need send anything that isn't possible via `SendKeys` or `SendInput`, you might have to use `SendMessage`.

Answer (score 0):

(Excuse me for duplicating. I cannot add a comment to the previous post)

AutoIt can automate WindowsForms. After it's installed, you'll find a help file, that is enough to work with.
You can create an EXE file and run it on any machine.